# How can i define ctx here?

Tags: discord.py

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Im here boss', description='Prefix: `n!help`', color=discord.Colour.from_rgb(249, 35, 142))
        embed.set_image(url='https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fe/1d/60/fe1d606ca0bcaf954a78cae3ed9c628b.gif')
        embed.set_footer(icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url, text = f'Brought here by {ctx.author.name}')
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

If i add ctx in the async def thing it shows an error and that it isnt defined and also in the footer it isnt defined. how do i define ctx in this thing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ctx.author.*` use `message.author.*`, though if you really want to get the `Context` (`ctx`) use the following:

```py
ctx = await client.get_context(message)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`get_context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_context) method.
Wherever you need to get the ctx variable, add something like this:

```py
ctx = await client.get_context(message)
```

You can also input a custom context as a second argument (`cls=MyCustomCtx`)