# using invoke() inside a daily loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm using the general framework to set up a daily recurring task from the top rated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57634182/13636965). This runs fine if all I want to do is print stuff in the channel specified in `target_channel_id`.

But I'm trying to call another function (with arguments) using `invoke()` from within the `called_once_a_day` function, something like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send('this works {}'.format(arg))
```

The problem is, there is a `ctx` in `foo` but no ctx in `called_once_a_day`. If I add `ctx` as an argument to `called_once_a_day(ctx)` and include the following line to call `foo`

```
await ctx.invoke(bot.get_command('foo'), arg='whatever')
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: called_once_a_day() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

I also tried removing the `ctx` argument from `called_once_a_day` and instead changing the way `invoke()` is called to

```
await bot.invoke(bot.get_command('foo'), arg='whatever')
```

but then I get this error:

```
TypeError: invoke() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg'
```

tldr I'm not sure how to call `invoke()` without a `ctx`, but adding a `ctx` throws an error.

edit:

Running

```
@tasks.loop(hours = 24) 
async def called_once_a_day(): 
    await ctx.invoke(bot.get_command('foo'), arg='whatever')
```

Throws the following error:
`NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined`

Comment: The first approach (`await ctx.invoke(bot.get_command('foo'), arg='whatever')`) works for me, though `arg` must be a keyword-only argument.

Comment: I edited my original post for the error I get with this

Comment: Related: [How do I define ctx here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67561037/how-can-i-define-ctx-here/67561061#67561061)

Comment: I looked at this, and I agree there needs to be a ctx or some kind of channel destination defined, but there's no `message` in this situation.

If don't have to call another command, and simply print to a channel, this works for me: `message_channel = bot.get_channel(id)` followed by `await message_channel.send(...)`. 

But I can't do `await message_channel.invoke(bot.get_command('foo'), arg='whatever')` without getting the error `AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'invoke'`. I think I need something like this though, but I don't know what exactly.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 main ways of invoking a command:

1. (new way)

```py
cmd = bot.get_command('foo')
await cmd(ctx, 'positional argument', keyword='argument')
```

2. (old way)

```py
cmd = bot.get_command('foo')
await ctx.invoke(cmd, 'positional argument', keyword='argument')
```

*Small note: you have to be careful when passing positional and keyword arguments*

---

There are 3 downsides to using this two methods:

1. The converters (the type hints) won't be triggered. You need to pass the correct types into the arguments.
2. Checks will be bypassed. You could invoke an owner only command with a non owner and it would still work (you can use [`Command.can_run`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.can_run) which will run all the checks and return a boolean)
3. If `ctx.invoke` was invoked outside of a command (eg `eval`), the error handler won't fire.

---

The third way is the one that actually handles all the checks and converters, though you cannot pass the arguments by yourself (I guess overwriting `ctx.args` will work didn't try it though)

```py
cmd = bot.get_command('foo')
ctx.command = cmd
await bot.invoke(ctx)
```

I don’t recommend using this method at all

Comment: The third method will still be a lot more complicated, especially if you start using subcommands and all. Just replacing the `.command` attribute could possibly mess things up quite a bit

Comment: In all 3 methods you listed, `ctx` is a required argument. But it goes back to my original question of what to do if `ctx` isn't an argument.

In the `called_once_a_day` function, there is no `ctx` and adding one throws an error.

Comment: Then it’s not possible to invoke the command at all, easiest solution is to create a function that takes a channel instance and just call it inside the task and the command

Comment: Another solution is to start the task in a command and pass ctx as an argument.

Comment: I was thinking something like the first suggestion as a workaround, except just copy pasting in another version of the function into the loop so that there's nothing to call, it just runs the code I feed it with the channel specified. Do you mind elaborating on your 2nd suggestion?

Comment: Have your loop function take `ctx` as an argument `async def called_once_a_day(ctx):` and start it inside a command passing `ctx`, i.e `called_once_ad_day.start(ctx)`

Comment: Doing this gives an error `NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined`. The problem is that inside the loop, there's no message or channel specified, so I think somehow this needs to be defined in order to have a `ctx` to use for the `invoke` command.

Comment: That's why I'm telling you to start the loop inside a command...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, and which one you do depends on what you want.

#### Method 1: You want to call the command as a function, ignoring all hooks, converters, cooldowns, permissions checks, etc.

For this, use [Command.__call__](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#discord.ext.commands.Command.__call__)

```py
command = bot.get_command("command name")
await command.__call__(ctx, arg="argument")
```

#### Method 2: You want to call the command, and you also want the bot to process checks and converters.

For this, you should use [Bot.invoke](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoke#discord.ext.commands.Bot.invoke). You should take the Context object, and change the `.command` attribute to the command you want.

```py
command = bot.get_command("command name")
ctx.command = command
await bot.invoke(ctx)
```

If you need to change the arguments passed to the command, use the first method. Note that it won't process converters, so you have to give the command the correct types.

Comment: I have the same question for your 2 methods, since both also require `ctx`. If I were to just write another function outside of my daily loop, I can include `ctx` as an argument and use any of these methods mentioned to call another command, no issues at all. But once I try to do this within the framework of a scheduled loop, it errors out.

Comment: @norinhara do you have a message inside of this loop?

Comment: No, there is no message or channel defined inside the loop. It is simply what you see I put in for the edit.