# Trying To Call a command from outside an async

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot (python) that has two functions.

First, it has commands that are typed in a channel using a hard coded prefix. Secondly, I use threading so I can schedule a specific command at a specific time. This allows both to run simultaneously ( The bot is constantly threading, and since its not in a loop, it is allowing the usage of other commands. The problem is, it's not working as expected, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any assistance would be appreciated.

I've tried various forms of this command, and the below is one of about 40 different methods I've tried. If you wish, I can indeed post the various methods I've tried thus far, but if you know a way to accomplish this in an easier fashion, it would be appreciated.

Please note that everything works perfectly except the client.get_command portion. I tested the counter and threading by inputing lines such as "print(f'The current time is {current_time}') So I know everything is operational except that call command.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.utils import get
import os
import sqlite3
import datetime
from sqlite3 import Error
import time
import threading

def checkTime():
  threading.Timer(1, checkTime).start()

  now = datetime.datetime.now()

  current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

  if current_time == '00:00:00':
    print('Its Time. . . ')
    client.get_command('manualcheckdisable')
  

checkTime()


@client.command()
async def manualcheckdisable(ctx):
  # Do things here manually by command, or on schedule at midnight
```

Comment: You should look at https://pypi.org/project/aioschedule/, or `discord.ext.tasks`

Comment: You're just getting the command, you're not calling it. A better idea would be to simply use an async function and [`discord.ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)

Comment: Take a look at one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67592311/using-invoke-inside-a-daily-loop/67593905#67593905) for invoking a command, though you always need `ctx`.

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen. WIth your direction, I've solved my problem. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help in the comments, I was able to resolve this by making a few changes:

First off, I have the bot running the loop right at the start with:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  guild = client.guilds[0]
  print('Bot Ready. . .')
  startloop.start()
```

Next, I have the task created as follows:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=30.0)
async def startloop():
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
  print(f'Current Time is {current_time}')
  if current_time == '00:00':
    print('Running Nightly Audit Loop. . .')# Do things. . .(about 150 lines of code)
```

Lastly, and I know this might not be best practices, but it works and thats the main thing. I created a new command, which is basically a copy of the loop, without the loop:

```
@client.command
async def manuallaunch(ctx):
  # Do things (about 150 lines of code)
```

Thank you for all that pointed me in the right direction.